# Streaming WAV Files in Adobe Air

Tags: jquery, flash, air

I am writing a basic Air app where one of the features is the ability to stream voicemail off of a local PBX. The voicemails are saved in WAV format and due to outside factors this cannot be changed. According to the Air docs there is no support for the audio tag because the flash player is built in, however, the flash player doesn't support wav files.

Was this just a large oversight on Adobe's part or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I think it's by design because WAV is really unsuitable for transferring through a network. Maybe this helps though: [Flash swf to play PCM WAV files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2557511)

Answer (score 0):

You could try encoding the wav files in mp3 and then playing them. Check out http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/.

You could also use a command line encoder using the nativeProcesses capability in AIR. Check out [this](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1142) for some details.